# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'float' and 'bool' when using .loc

Tags: python, pandas, typeerror, operands

Given the following DataFrame -

| **json_path** | **Reporting Group** | **Entity/Grouping** | **Entity ID** | **Adjusted Value (Today, No Div, USD)** | **Adjusted TWR (Current Quarter, No Div, USD)** | **Adjusted TWR (YTD, No Div, USD)** | **Annualized Adjusted TWR (Since Inception, No Div, USD)** | **Adjusted Value (No Div, USD)** | **TWR Audit Note** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| data.attributes.total.children.[0].children.[0].children.[0] | Barrack Family | William and Rupert Trust | 9957007 | -1.44 |  |  |  | -1.44 |  |
| data.attributes.total.children.[0].children.[0].children.[0].children.[0] | Barrack Family | Cash | - | -1.44 |  |  |  | -1.44 |  |
| data.attributes.total.children.[0].children.[0].children.[1] | Barrack Family | Gratia Holdings No. 2 LLC | 8413655 | 55491732.66 | -0.971018847 | -0.971018847 | 11.52490309 | 55491732.66 |  |
| data.attributes.total.children.[0].children.[0].children.[1].children.[0] | Barrack Family | Investment Grade Fixed Income | - | 18469768.6 |  |  |  | 18469768.6 |  |
| data.attributes.total.children.[0].children.[0].children.[1].children.[1] | Barrack Family | High Yield Fixed Income | - | 3668982.44 | -0.205356545 | -0.205356545 | 4.441190127 | 3668982.44 |  |

I have a `def databases_creation()` function which uses `.loc` to strip out dataframe rows that don't meet a criteria, before saving the dataframe as `perf_asset_class_df`. Subsequently, the `def twr_exceptions_logic()` function is then **supposed** to strip out rows where the `Entity/Grouping` column value != 'Cash' and if either the `Adjusted TWR (Current Quarter, No Div, USD),` Adjusted TWR (YTD, No Div, USD)`or`Annualized Adjusted TWR (Since Inception, No Div, USD)` is == " [empty]

The Functions: here are the functions, as described -

```
def databases_creation():
    df = data_cleansing()
    
#   CREATING DATAFRAME FOR PERF. BY ASSET CLASS (EX. ILLIQUID) - STANDARD REPORT PG.4
    perf_asset_class_df = df[df['json_path'].str.contains(r'(?:\.children\.\[\d+\]){4}')]

    return perf_asset_class_df
```

**AND**

```
def twr_exceptions_logic():
    perf_asset_class_df = databases_creation()

    m1 = perf_asset_class_df.loc[(perf_asset_class_df['Entity/Grouping']!= 'Cash')]
    m2 = perf_asset_class_df[['Adjusted TWR (Current Quarter, No Div, USD)',
                              'Adjusted TWR (YTD, No Div, USD)',
                              'Annualized Adjusted TWR (Since Inception, No Div, USD)']].eq('').any(1)
    perf_asset_class_df.loc[m1&m2]
    
    return perf_asset_class_df
```

**Issue:** I am getting a `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'float' and 'bool'` which points to `def twr_exceptions_logic()`, specifically the `perf_asset_class_df.loc[m1&m2]`

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\.conda\envs\JPDevelopment\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\array_ops.py in na_logical_op(x, y, op)
    300         #  (xint or xbool) and (yint or bool)
--> 301         result = op(x, y)
    302     except TypeError:

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'float' and 'bool'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\WILLIA~1.FOR\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_18756/2156183286.py in <module>
      9 
     10     return reporting_group_df, unknown_df, perf_asset_class_df, perf_entity_df, perf_entity_group_df
---> 11 twr_exceptions_logic()

C:\Users\WILLIA~1.FOR\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_18756/2156183286.py in twr_exceptions_logic()
      6                               'Adjusted TWR (YTD, No Div, USD)',
      7                               'Annualized Adjusted TWR (Since Inception, No Div, USD)']].eq('').any(1)
----> 8     perf_asset_class_df.loc[m1&m2]
      9 
     10     return reporting_group_df, unknown_df, perf_asset_class_df, perf_entity_df, perf_entity_group_df

~\.conda\envs\JPDevelopment\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\common.py in new_method(self, other)
     68         other = item_from_zerodim(other)
     69 
---> 70         return method(self, other)
     71 
     72     return new_method

~\.conda\envs\JPDevelopment\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\arraylike.py in __and__(self, other)
     68     @unpack_zerodim_and_defer("__and__")
     69     def __and__(self, other):
---> 70         return self._logical_method(other, operator.and_)
     71 
     72     @unpack_zerodim_and_defer("__rand__")

~\.conda\envs\JPDevelopment\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in _arith_method(self, other, op)
   6938         self, other = ops.align_method_FRAME(self, other, axis, flex=True, level=None)
   6939 
-> 6940         new_data = self._dispatch_frame_op(other, op, axis=axis)
   6941         return self._construct_result(new_data)
   6942 

~\.conda\envs\JPDevelopment\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in _dispatch_frame_op(self, right, func, axis)
   6977             # TODO operate_blockwise expects a manager of the same type
   6978             with np.errstate(all="ignore"):
-> 6979                 bm = self._mgr.operate_blockwise(
   6980                     # error: Argument 1 to "operate_blockwise" of "ArrayManager" has
   6981                     # incompatible type "Union[ArrayManager, BlockManager]"; expected

~\.conda\envs\JPDevelopment\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py in operate_blockwise(self, other, array_op)
   1407         Apply array_op blockwise with another (aligned) BlockManager.
   1408         """
-> 1409         return operate_blockwise(self, other, array_op)
   1410 
   1411     def _equal_values(self: BlockManager, other: BlockManager) -> bool:

~\.conda\envs\JPDevelopment\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\ops.py in operate_blockwise(left, right, array_op)
     61     res_blks: list[Block] = []
     62     for lvals, rvals, locs, left_ea, right_ea, rblk in _iter_block_pairs(left, right):
---> 63         res_values = array_op(lvals, rvals)
     64         if left_ea and not right_ea and hasattr(res_values, "reshape"):
     65             res_values = res_values.reshape(1, -1)

~\.conda\envs\JPDevelopment\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\array_ops.py in logical_op(left, right, op)
    389         filler = fill_int if is_self_int_dtype and is_other_int_dtype else fill_bool
    390 
--> 391         res_values = na_logical_op(lvalues, rvalues, op)
    392         # error: Cannot call function of unknown type
    393         res_values = filler(res_values)  # type: ignore[operator]

~\.conda\envs\JPDevelopment\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\array_ops.py in na_logical_op(x, y, op)
    306             x = ensure_object(x)
    307             y = ensure_object(y)
--> 308             result = libops.vec_binop(x.ravel(), y.ravel(), op)
    309         else:
    310             # let null fall thru

~\.conda\envs\JPDevelopment\lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\ops.pyx in pandas._libs.ops.vec_binop()

~\.conda\envs\JPDevelopment\lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\ops.pyx in pandas._libs.ops.vec_binop()

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'float' and 'bool'
```

Does anyone have any hints/tips on where my code might be faltering?

Comment: `m1` is some kind of float data and `m2` is some kind of boolean data. I'm not sure the functions work, but maybe you're missing an `.any(1)` on `m1`?

Comment: first use `print()` to see what you have in `m1` and `m2`

Comment: as for me you should create `m1` without `perf_asset_class_df.loc[]` - only `m1 = (perf_asset_class_df['Entity/Grouping'] != 'Cash')`